# Jenkins ec2 plugin ssh keys

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I  have a groovy script which will configure AWS ec2 plugin with required data. I am able to configure all other inputs. I need to give private key in same region, is there any way that i can generate and configure this key in grrovy script. followed below document and template.
https://gist.github.com/vrivellino/97954495938e38421ba4504049fd44ea
https://github.com/jenkinsci/ec2-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/ec2/SlaveTemplate.java

Answer (score 1):

This will help you to get Jenkins private keys:

```
EC2Cloud cloud = Jenkins.instance.clouds.find { it instanceof EC2Cloud }
KeyPair key_pair= cloud.getKeyPair()
private_key_text = key_pair.keyMaterial
def secret_key = hudson.util.Secret.decrypt(cloud.getSecretKey()).toString()
```

Comment: That's amazing. Thank you! I had to tweak it to work with my Jenkins installation but you helped me find the way.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the right answer to your question, but this is where Google led me when I wanted to decipher the private key for the EC2 Jenkins plugin.
This worked for me with Jenkins **2.190.2**.

```
import hudson.plugins.ec2.AmazonEC2Cloud
def cloud = Jenkins.instance.clouds.find { it instanceof AmazonEC2Cloud }
println cloud.getKeyPair().keyMaterial
```